# Angularjs why this html page(view) does not integrate with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

[image: Browser screen shot]
I have an Angularjs site that works. However one html file(view) does not integrate with Angular. The flight fields are not show and the button is not active.

Can anybody help?

```
 <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar="" role="navigation">

  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name"><h1><a ui-sref="client.payment">Pagamento</a></h1></li>
  </ul>

</nav>
<div id="sidePanelContent">

  <a ui-sref="^" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}" class="closeSidePanel"><img src="images/admin/botao-fechar.png" alt="Fechar"></a>

  <h1>Pagamento do Voo</h1>

  <div>
    <p ng-show="flight"><strong>Voo:</strong> {{flight.fromairport.name}}  &#10141; {{flight.toairport.name}}</p>
    <p ng-show="flight"><strong>Horário:</strong> {{flight.departure | formatDateTime}}h</p>
    <p ng-show="flight"><strong>Lugares disponíveis:</strong> {{flight.availableseats}}</p>
    <p ng-show="flight"><strong>Aeronave:</strong> {{flight.airplane.name}}</p>
    <p ng-show="flight"><strong>Preço atual:</strong> R$ {{flight.price | formatPrice}}</p>
  </div>

  <button class="button" ui-sref="client.payment({flight:flightid})" >Pagar com Paypal</button>
```

----------------   Java script -----------------

```
    'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name flyvipApp.controller:AboutCtrl
 * @description
 * # AboutCtrl
 * Controller of the flyvipApp
 */
angular.module('flyvipApp')
  .controller('PaymentCtrl', function ($scope, SharedData, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, Authorization, $http) {

    var api = "http://flyvip.com.br/app/api/";
    var userid = Authorization.currentUser().user.id;

    $rootScope.sidePanel = false;
    SharedData.selectedMenu.setItem('voos');
    $scope.menu = SharedData.selectedMenu;
    $rootScope.homeClient = false;
    $scope.orderedFlights = {data: []};
    $scope.flag = false;
    var _flightid = _id;
    var _airplaneid = $scope.flight.airplane.id;
    var _dateofdeparture = $scope.flight.dateofdeparture;
    var _dateofarrival = $scope.flight.dateofarrival;
    var _airportdeparture = $scope.flight.fromairport.id;
    var _airportarrival = $scope.flight.toairport.id;
    var _price = $scope.flight.price;
    var _seats = $scope.flight.availableseats;
    var _status = $scope.flight.flightstatus;
    var _reason = $scope.flight.reason;

    var flight = {
      flightid: _flightid,
      airplaneid: _airplaneid,
      dateofdeparture: _dateofdeparture,
      dateofarrival: _dateofarrival,
      airportofdeparture: _airportdeparture,
      airportofarrival: _airportarrival,
      price: _price,
      seats: _seats,
      flightstatus: _status,
      reason: _reason,
      invoicenum: "122344",
      passengerid: $scope.passengerid
    };
    $http({method: "POST", url: api + "DoWriteLog.php",msg:'Entrei neste script!', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}).success(function(response, status, headers, config) {
  });
    $http({method: "POST", url: api + "DoPayment.php", data: flight, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}).success(function(response, status, headers, config) {
      if (response.success) {
        $scope.flag = true;
      }
      else
        $scope.flag = false;
    })});
```

Comment: I don't see an `ng-controller` attribute anywhere.  As it stands there is not enough information in the question to make an answer.  What do you mean by *does not integrate*?  How are you using it?

Comment: I mean the fields of flight are not shown and the button does not call client.payment script.

Comment: I was assigned to this project and I have little knowledge of Angular. You mean I have to assign a ng-controller to this page? In the top of the page?

Comment: Have you included <script src="angular.js"></script>? Do you have ng-app and ng-controller declared somewhere? Provide js source please.

Comment: Yes ng-app and ng-controller are declared.

Comment: I included the java script controller source code in the main question

Comment: please update your HTML to show us where ng-app and ng-controller are declared.... just saying that they are doesn't help diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning flight object to scope try this:

```
$scope.flight = {
...
}
```

Also I can see that most of the variables are not declared in that object except flight.fromairport.
I'm not sure where are you getting the data from, but make sure it is assigned to $scope.flight at some point.

Comment: The flight object is assigned to scope in another file. What I cannot understand is why the flight object fields are treated as text by the browser. I am attaching the screen shot

Comment: Provide full html (from View Page Source). Where  the part of ng-app ng-controller is declared.

Comment: Maybe for the same reason? Where is 'client' object assigned in the scope? does it have payment method? Try debugging it.

Comment: I edit the original post to include the route. I think that the problem is that the child view's controller do not update the $scope. (I don't know why).

Comment: the problem was solved when I include the following statement in the controller: $scope.saving = false;